# What's the difference between Curless VS Moller algortihms for ray tracing of triangles?

Tags: raytracing

Moller is a universal and fastest algorithm used for ray tracing triangles.
It based on barycentrics coordinates.
Even if Weber(2016) can be better than Moller.

What's the difference with Curless algorithm and why is-it always better?

Curless : https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep557/10au/lectures/triangle_intersection.pdf
Moller : https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10867651.1997.10487468

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curless needs to

- compute the normal vector
- do a triangle inside outside test (3 edge equation test)
- compute barycentric coordiantes

Moeler does in one go compute barycentric coordiantes - boom! Less calculations.

Neverthless, checkout [Watertight Ray/Triangle Intersection](https://jcgt.org/published/0002/01/05/).